# How to add check constraint on time with a timestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to add a constraint that time entered in a column is only after 8:00 am. I've tried

```
alter table toy_store ADD CHECK (store_opening_time > TIMESTAMP '2013-05-05 08:00:00');
```

This only allows entry of timestamp greater than 5th May 8:00 am. I want to write a query that checks if the entry is after 8:00 am notwithstanding the date.

Comment: Why are you storing the time in a timestamp rather than an interval?

Comment: I need to store both time and date at which the store opens

Comment: So you have more than one row per toy store? (I'd think it should be a row per day). I can't see you needing to store the date, even the column name is time and you're trying to avoid the date here. Even if you do need to store the date you can still use an interval...

Comment: okay..i'm new at this. i'll see how to work with interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
 alter table toy_store ADD CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM store_opening_time) > 8 || NULL);
```

Comment: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: "store_opening_time" column is nullable?

Comment: "store_opening_time" is nullable

Comment: Okay, try this : 

alter table toy_store ADD CHECK (extract(hour from cast(to_char(store_opening_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp)) > 8 || NULL);

I just edited answer.

Comment: pff. what is "store_opening_time" data type? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57368/discussion-between-ersin-tarhan-and-mak).